# Implementing StatsD/Graphite with Python

Tags: python, statsd

So I've got Etsy's [StatsD](https://github.com/etsy/statsd) and Graphite working on OS X 10.9.3.

I'm trying to implement them now using Python, and I'd prefer not to use [python-statsd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-statsd), since I'd like to understand how to use the tech by itself before resorting to a library (what if I need to use Ruby/PHP later, then I wouldn't understand the basic mechanics).

I.e. I'm trying to use Python to send app data to StatsD, which will then be displayed in Graphite.

Inside my app, I'm using an exact copy of Steve Ivy's [python_example.py](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/examples/python_example.py).

In my code, I call the increment function like this:

```
from statsd import StatsdClient
client = StatsdClient()
client.increment('somename.someval')
```

Here is the error that is raised:

```
File "/Users/bengrunfeld/Desktop/Work/code/wf-ghconsole/console/statsd.py", line 163, in send
udp_sock.sendto(":".join(item).encode('utf-8'), addr)
....
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 234, in _MakeRealSyncCall
raise pickle.loads(response_pb.exception())
RuntimeError: error('illegal IP address string passed to inet_pton',)
```

Here is the value of what is being sent by `udp_sock.sendto`:
`('somename.someval:1|c', ('localhost', 8125))`

Link to my code: https://github.com/bengrunfeld-wf/gae-github-console/blob/statsd/console/statsd.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok, but the first thing to do is try running the code outside of app engine. If his works, then confirm whether or not app engine will do UDP - if I recall correctly it will not - I had to create a http proxy last time I implemented this with app engine.

Comment: I think you're right about GAE and sending out UDP. Will check it out tomorrow.